# How to generate thesis or a question out of a quote/quotes?

Tags: quotes, writers-block

In an effort to overcome my writer's block, I've come up with an exercise, which I've pieced together from all the material I've read on dealing with writer's block.

However, now I am struggling with the exercise, and unable to complete it.

---

### The Exercise

It's easier to write an opinion or make a persuasive argument based on a given question. For example:

> The best way to keep healthy is to perform daily physical exercise. Do you agree or disagree?

In the exercise, **take a set of quotes with a common theme,** and **write an essay responding to the quotes,** posing a question or a thesis based on them. (This is the writing aspect that I am trying to improve.)

---

I am finding this very tricky with multiple quotes. Most of the time I am hearing these quotes for the first time and when writing a timed piece without familiarity with the context, it is tough. Often the thesis and/or the content of the written argument is misleading. My writers block is also contributing to the difficulty.

I am searching for materials that can help to understand and as rules/guidelines in generating a thesis out of a related set of quotes. So far I came across [this.](http://public.wsu.edu/~campbelld/topic.htm) Possibly working-tips that could move me a step (at least a 1cm) from my writing struggle (writing the whole day but unable to construct a logical flow even for a short opinion piece with counter arguments and refutation).

Comment: Heya! Welcome to Writers.SE. This is a little unclear -- can you explain the situation here? Are you being _provided_ a set of quotes, and you need to  form a thesis _based_ on them? Is this in the context of an assignment? If so, for what kind of class? Can you give an example of a set of quotes?

Comment: Also, if you could fix/explain the line _"Often the thesis is mislead or/and the content of the written argument."_ I think you've got an error there, and I don't understand the problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: I'm putting this on-hold so you can clarify it -- comment to clarify, or edit your post, and I'll be happy to reopen :)

Comment: I've proposed some edits.  See what you think, and roll back if you want to.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you find yourself spinning your wheels, have been somewhat incapacitated by doubt, and have found yourself unproductive in your writing attempts, as a result; and you have set yourself timed writing exercises to try to avoid spinning your wheels agonizing over some aspect of your writing for long periods.  Given a collections of statements, you would like to articulate a position, and then write a persuasive argument to support that position.  But it's not going well, because the collection of statements takes a lot of time to analyze.  Did I get that right?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to work from a different type of writing prompt.

Comment: I am glad to receive all your feedback. It is a relief and ineed @aparente001 bulls eye! I am trying to give myself timed exercises of unknown territories to prevent the roller coaster rides and rotting on one topic for days if not weeks for any productivity or a useful writing habit being formed. I desperately want to get back at my top notch (for my level) essay and article wtiting skill. My list of references from elements of style, grammar rules to the elements of eloquence or even any high school, college materials, moocs do not seem to bring much aid. I am open to advice. Torch please.

Comment: @Standback I feel good to see your overwhelming support. This is no assignment. But I tried to search online to find the types of challenging exercises to pull my strings back and get the loose nuts and bolts tightened up. Feel free to edit it. As I read it just now, I realized the queation is in the *dark*. However much better after ya edits.

Comment: Is this an exercise you found online? Can you point us to it, quote it? It sounds like you've chosen a writing prompt that isn't really working for you, so having the actual prompt would make the question much clearer :)

Comment: On mobile, unable to format comments. I read so many articles about resolving writers block. And my particular interest is in beautiful writing. Whether it is an op ed, editorial, event, book review, classics and poem analysis or writing in context. So I put bits and pieces together to think this would help me. www.easyliteracy.com

Comment: This may sound strange, but I will suggest that you work with middle school and high school practice test questions.  In New York, for the annual state tests, you have to read a text, draw inferences, answer questions and cite specific bits of text to back up your position.  This might help you get unstuck.  If you want to give this a try, start here: https://www.engageny.org/resource/released-2016-3-8-ela-and-mathematics-state-test-questions, and download only the files that say "English Language Arts Test Released Questions."  There will be one for each grade level...

Comment: ... You could start with grade 6 or 7 and work your way up to grade 12.  To overcome writer's block, it's not really necessary to write a *War and Peace.* // Whether you try my idea or not, I hope you'll let us know how it goes.

Comment: @bonCodigo : I've edited your question according to your explanation here in the comments. Have I captured the issue correctly? Feel free to re-edit.

Comment: (My difficulty here is, you've made up your own exercise, and it doesn't seem to be helping you. And so you're asking "How do I do this exercise I made up?". It might be that this isn't the greatest exercise for you right now? Also, if you could explain better _what_ has got you stuck? If it's reading the quotes out of context... can you use quotes _with_ context? If it's the disjointed nature of multiple quotes, maybe you should be working on building more evocative quote-sets? It's kind of hard to tell.)

Comment: @Standback ok so what exercise should I follow? My main issue, I just can't keep a logical flow to pen the piece. It is frustrating. We all writers just want to focus on one thing, one bit at a time to build the depth and quality for a given time frame and a length. e.g. I want to write about a grain of sand that stuck in my eye... or feeling of biting a sand grain in food... I wanna express how it feels, set up the atmosphere before and after. I solely wanna focus on that sand grain, it's made, it's origins in the context how it affects the person...

Comment: However when I sit down with a quote for e.g., I feel there's a universe of information out there. But nothing is in my head. No evidence, no stores, no experience that I could think of build a compelling arugument. There's nothing wrong with the quotes I pick whether it's one quote for 10 from goodreads.com or other quote repositories about one topic, may it be education, politics (not my favourite), relationships, truth, peace, love, emotions, healthcare etc

Comment: @aparente001 is it possible for you to open a chat window? The comments are getting super long. In Stackoverflow we have blackboard for developers/coders to chat.

Comment: @bonCodigo - Quick answer for now.  Yes, sure, but it might not be today.  You can open a chat associated with this question and invite me.  Also, can you look at one of the sample exams and see if any of the questions appeal to you as simple warm-up exercises?  My motto is Start somewhere!

Comment: @aparente001 I am gonna give your set of exercises a try. Certain, just buzz me here with some date n time before you are ready for a chat. So I'll create the chat. Earlier chat rooms get closed auto when inactive.